# How o create a cronjob that import data into mongodb from remote csv/xml webservice?

Tags: mongodb, rest, ssh, cron, mongoimport

Hi there i need to create a cronjob that run every 30 minutes a mongodbimport command on mi server. Basically i need to sync a RESTAPI webservice with my MongoDB server. How i can do this task?
Webservice returns thousands of products in csv or xml format.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write script/program (you can use languages like PHP, Python, JavaScript (NodeJS), ...), which will parse CSV/XML and puts the data into MongoDB. Then run this script/program via cron.